# Firebase video to videoview not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-videoview

I am able to record and able to upload that video to firebase from my android app but not being able to play or stream(whatever is possible) to videoview. I am actually trying to get in it the recycler view but since it didn't work trying something simpler.

I read many post here in stackoverflow and tried almost all of them but none worked.So posting new question.

My code are as follows:

```
 VideoView video;
//String video_url = "http://file2.video9.in/english/movie/2014/x-men-_days_of_future_past/X-Men-%20Days%20of%20Future%20Past%20Trailer%20-%20[Webmusic.IN].3gp";//this one works if i use it
String video_url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/longidcharacters-video.mp4?alt=media&token=xxxxx"; 
//but this link from firebase does not work, i usually fetch it from online
ProgressDialog pd;
Button playButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_video);

    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.Videoview1);
    playButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton1);

    pd = new ProgressDialog(ShowVideoActivity.this);
    pd.setMessage("Buffering video please wait...");
    pd.show();

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(video_url);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);


    video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //close the progress dialog when buffering is done
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            video.start();
        }
    });
```

It says "cannot play this video". The format is mp4(recorded from camera). However, if I play that 3gp one(which is commented now),it works fine.
What can i do? Is there any player I can try? I am just trying to stream or play video that is uploaded to firebase storage.